# Use Windows Azure Active Dirctory for Apache LDAP authentication

Tags: apache, azure

I have a php website which runs on an apache webserver in azure.

I want to authenticate users via ldap(mod_authnz_ldap) in ordre to manage the users only once.

Is it possible to use the Azure Active Directory as an ldap server? And if yes, where can i manage the users/group/xyz?

Or do i have to setup a standalone ldap service for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. LDAP is not supported by Windows Azure Active Directory.
Official doc [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/identity/). Quote:

> Today, Windows Azure AD isn’t a complete replacement for on-premises
>   Windows Server AD. As already mentioned, the cloud directory has a
>   much simpler schema, and **it’s also missing** things such as group
>   policy, the ability to store information about machines, and **support
>   for LDAP**.

You have think of leveraging the SSO support Windows Azure AD via OAuth/SAMLP/WS-Federation and re-engineer your auth/authz layer.

Answer (score 2):

Stumble upon this old post. LDAP is now supported via Azure Directory Services which supports traditionnal methods of authentication, like Kerberos/NTLM and LDAP.